# Replace NSTextContainer of UITextView when loading from XIB/Storyboard

Tags: uitextview, textkit

I've made a custom subclass of `NSTextStorage`, which processes text as I need it to be processed.

To use this on a text view I need to create a `NSTextContainer` and a `NSLayoutManager`, and then assign the container to the `UITextView`.

This works without any problems if done programatically.

Is there a way how to change the text container and layout manager after the text view was loaded from a Storyboard or XIB file?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to the problem?